# Simplify an if statement with a method C#

Tags: c#, if-statement

I was wondering if there is any possible way to simplify this.

```
if (string != "")
{
   dataGridView1.Rows.Add(string);
}
```

All I can find is how to shorten if statements which return a value, not execute a method like mine.

Comment: It is already simple, what do you need to simplify?

Comment: Note that it's also helpful to provide code snippets which would compile - `string` is a keyword here. Using any valid identifier would be better.

Comment: `if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(yourString)) {` the better way for testing string empty. Also use `string.Empty` instead of `""`

Comment: Your primary goal should usually be to leave code that is simple for the future reader (another programmer or yourself in 6 months time) to understand. Do you think the code you've shown is *unclear* in what it's doing? If not, leave it alone.

Comment: you could use the ternary operator and delegates but that would only increase complexity and should be avoided unless you have a valid reason for doing so.

Comment: I was actually trying to get rid of parentheses. But I guess Damien has a point. I will leave it as it already is. Thank you!

Comment: If you have a single line of code you could get rid of the curly braces. But this can be quite dangerous, i.e. is someone adds something else after the if-statement. So it is best to only do this when you have many similar statements and the readability improvement of more compact code outweigh the risks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not much to do from where you are already. I would only suggest inverting the if statement to reduce nesting. You could also remove the braces by using this method like this:

```
if (string == "") return;
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(string);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if a string is not empty and then add it to your dataGridView1.Rows at multiple places in your code, you could declare an Action<string> like

```
Action<string> AddRowIfInputNotEmpty = new Action<string>(input =>
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(input);
});
```

And then call it like `AddRowIfInputNotEmpty.Invoke("MyString");` whenever you need it

Comment: I tried to use it, but it gave me CS0236 error. I solved it this way though:
Action<string, DataGridView> AddRowIfInputNotEmpty = (input, dgv) ...
Is there any way that I can do like you did?

Comment: That error occurs when you try to paste my snippet in your namespace. To solve this put `Action<string> AddRowIfInputNotEmpty;` in your namespace; and in your constructor or any other method you initialize the action like `AddRowIfInputNotEmpty = new Action<string>(input =>...`
That should fix it.

Comment: Oh, amazing! Thank you, you literally opened my eyes. I guess I could make use of it somewhere else as well!

Answer (score 0):

Create an extension method `AddIfNotEmpty` for `DataGridViewRowCollection`:

```
public static void AddIfNotEmpty(this DataGridViewRowCollection rows, string value)
{
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        rows.Add(value);
}
```

Usage:

```
dataGridView1.Rows.AddIfNotEmpty(stringValue);
```

Answer (score -1):

Since Add method returns an int you can simplify (uglify if you ask me) using the discards operator:

```
_ = yourString != "" ? dataGridView1.Rows.Add(yourString) : 0;
```

Or as Jeremy Pointed out:

```
_ = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(yourString) ? Add(list, yourString) : 0;
```

Answer (score -2):

(As a note, when checking the equality of a string, you should use `stringVar.equals()` Also, when looking for null or whitespace data, you can use `stringVar.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()`)

Well, you can try

```
//Note: I haven't tested this and you may need to fiddle it a bit

    if(!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stringVar)) dataGridView1.Rows.Add(stringVar);

//you can also use something like this

    !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stringVar) ? //if true : //if false;
```

Let me know if this doesn't satisfy your question and I will attempt to amend my statements.

Comment: In Java you *should* use a `.equals()` method, but in C# an `==` works fine as value comparison

Comment: Sure, == works fine but it's not a best practice. And OP was asking how to simplify his if statement. If you see, my answer only mentions the .equals() method but I say it is better not use use either == or .equals() for his needs..